# Sveltekit: Page cannot load when importing s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, svelte, server-side-rendering, sveltekit

Im making a sveltekit app, and im trying to make a function that uploads files to s3. Here's how it goes:

+page.svelte:

```
async function uploadModel() {
        uploading = true;



        let voiceModel: VoiceModel = get(voiceModelStore);

        const id = //make a random id
            'voiceModel-' +
            Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) +
            Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);

        voiceModel.id = id;
        voiceModel.createdAt = Timestamp.now();
        voiceModel.uploaderName = $userData!.username;
        voiceModel.fileUrls = await uploadZip(modelName);


        const imageUrl = await uploadImage(imageFile);

        

        voiceModel.imageUrl = imageUrl;



        await uploadVoiceModel(voiceModel);

        goto(`/models/${voiceModel.id}`);

    }
```

helper.ts

```
export async function uploadImage(file: File) {
    const path = `images/${file.name}`;
    const imageUrl = await uploadFile(file, path);
    return imageUrl;
}
```

wasabiRepo.ts

```
export async function uploadWasabiFile(blob: Blob, path: string): Promise<string> {
    const params = {
        Bucket: 'voclone',
        Key: path,
        Body: blob
    };

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // s3.upload(params, (error: any, data: { Location: string | PromiseLike<string> }) => {
        //  if (error) {
        //      reject(error);
        //  } else {
        //      resolve(data.Location);
        //  }
        // });
    });
}
```

The actual wasabi repo is being minimal right now because thats where the issue is coming up. As it is right now, there are no issues. But when i add

```
import { S3 } from 'aws-sdk';
```

The page fails to load, and gives the +error.svelte

The only error message coming out is

```
ReferenceError: global is not defined
    at node_modules/buffer/index.js (index.js:43:30)
    at __require2 (chunk-YBOLLQGG.js?v=878e68cd:16:50)
    at node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/browserHashUtils.js (browserHashUtils.js:1:14)
    at __require2 (chunk-YBOLLQGG.js?v=878e68cd:16:50)
    at node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/browserHmac.js (browserHmac.js:1:17)
    at __require2 (chunk-YBOLLQGG.js?v=878e68cd:16:50)
    at node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/browserCryptoLib.js (browserCryptoLib.js:1:12)
    at __require2 (chunk-YBOLLQGG.js?v=878e68cd:16:50)
    at node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/browser_loader.js (browser_loader.js:4:19)
    at __require2 (chunk-YBOLLQGG.js?v=878e68cd:16:50)
```

Really not sure where to go from here. Anyone seen this before?

Thanks!